# How would you draw non-similar geometry from the same Vertex Buffer?

Tags: c++, directx

I've been doing quite a bit of research but I still do not fully understand how to accomplish this. I've managed to duplicate a single piece of geometry with the same vertex buffer (Have 2 on screen) but I do not know how to render two different pieces of geometry (Non-similar, different dimensions, etc) from the same vertex buffer. I had the idea of building a mesh class that would also house its on vertex buffer but the implications of calling CreateVertexBuffer would easily destroy my program. I am not asking for a hand out but more of a point in the right direction. I am still fairly new to DirectX but I have some experience with OpenGL. Pseudo-code is more than welcomed as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all: Why do you want to store several models in one vertex buffer? The creation of a buffer is a one-time cost. Setting a vertex buffer for rendering has some minor performance penalty, but usually it is not worth the effort to merge vertex buffers. The basic idea is to use the offset parameter that most draw calls take to specify which region of the vertex buffer to draw.

Comment: I was under the impression that storing multiple models in the same vertex buffer would be the most efficient way of doing this. If not, would my mesh idea be better than using a single vertex buffer?

Comment: It *might* be more efficient to use a single VB. You should test how the performance differs if you consider to implement this. I guess it's not much. The mesh class is a good idea. Even if you use a single VB (then the mesh would store offsets and lengths).

Comment: Okay, I will test this when I get back to my computer. Thank you very much for the advice.